# Use Case for Static Resource Allocation in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Is dynamic allocation preferred to static allocation always? In other words, is there any situation we will be benefiting from allocating fixed resources?

Comment: Static allocation is definitely preferred mode for streaming applications, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24815

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of fixed resource allocation is predictability.

You will know exactly how much resources your job can use at any given time.

In case your are switching to dynamic allocation and your job runs on a shared cluster you might have times where the resources are not sufficient for the current workloads as the job's resource request gets queued up. This could cause unintended delaysand other unpredicted behavior.

Fixed resources are also easier to set up as you do not need an external shuffle service which is required for dynamic allocation.